# The activationCode is null in my method input when I click the email Verification link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, registration, email-verification

In the name of God

Hi all. I'm creating registration for my mvc 5 website in VS 2017.It has Email confirmation in it. the URL link for activation will be received completely in  Email. when I click , it works and it exactly comes to my controller on the correct ActionMethod but I don't know why the activationCode is null! :|
While before it worked correctly, I mean the Activation code was not null. I don't know what happend to it!
[image]
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

**Edited:**

```
 public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Password",
       url: "{controller}/{action}/{passwordResetCode}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Authentication", action = "ResetPassword" }
   );
        routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Activation",
       //url: "{controller}/{action}/{activationCode}",
       url: "Authentication/VerifyAccount/{activationCode}", 
       defaults: new { controller = "Authentication", action = "VerifyAccount" }
   );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide us with an example of the URL sent to the user email beside the action which receive this url and display the code page

Comment: var verifyURL = "/Authentication/VerifyTheAccount/" + activationCode;            var link = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, verifyURL); Example:http://localhost:0000/Authentication/VerifyTheAccount/5fd21531-cbd7-4a41-9522-839f32c50300

Comment: and inside the controller you should accept a parameter of name id and the type id GUID, beside that check your route to see whether if it accepts {id} parameter

Comment: @MahmoudHeretani thanks for your attention to my question. I edited the question and I've put another image in it. Would you please have a look?

Comment: @MahmoudHeretani can you please give me an example. I think I have to put the route on the Action. but don't know what to write correctly.

Comment: You can check the example in the first answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your default route accepts a parameter named `id`, not `activationCode`. You either need to change the controller method to

```
public ActionResult VerifyTheAccount(string id)
```

and change the link to set the `id`, for example (from your comments)

```
var verifyURL = "/Authentication/VerifyTheAccount/" + activationCode
```

or using the preferred `Url.Action()` method

```
var verifyURL = '@Url.Action("VerifyTheAccount", "Authentication", new { id = activationCode })
```

Alternatively you need to create a specific route definition before the `DefaultRoute`

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Activation",
   url: "Authentication/VerifyTheAccount/{activationCode}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Authentication", action = "VerifyTheAccount" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: well I did the same. But no answer I got.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand you comment. What do you mean _But no answer I got._?

Comment: Y.W.C I didn't get any answer. You know? Now I understood that it's better to specify each actionMerhod's route on top of it and don't change the default Rout.config. But I don't know what to write exactly on top of my actionMethods. Do you know?

Comment: Exactly as per my answer - you create a specific route before the default - in your case it has `url: "Authentication/VerifyTheAccount/{activationCode}",`

Comment: on top of the Action method? like VerifyTheAcount?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand what you are saying. Use the code I gave you exactly.

Comment: The thing that you wrote is exactly what I have in my project. it still sends null value to my VerifyAccount. Because I have the bellowing code on top of it: routes.MapRoute(
   name: "PasswordReset",
   url: "Authentication/ResetPassword/{passwordResetCode}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Authentication", action = "ResetPassword", passwordResetCode = = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );

Comment: No it is not! Look very carefully at the first route - in particular the url - it is NOT  `url: "{controller}/{action}/{activationCode}",` - it is **url: "Authentication/VerifyTheAccount/{activationCode}"**

Comment: There is a difference - in the answer you accepted (which is wrong) - the first route matches any url with 3 segments - e.g. it matches `/Home/Index/1` and the `Default` route will never be hit. But in my answer - only a url starting with `/Authentication/VerifyTheAccount` will match the 1st route. Any other url will not match and hit the `Default` route

Comment: please look  at my question. I edited the Rout.Config like you said. but still it sends null value.

Comment: Now you have gone and added another route first which matches anything - (it has nothing to do with this question) - but it would need to be `url: "Authentication/ResetPassword/{passwordResetCode}",` - again it needs to be a specific route

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve what you need you have to change the action parameter name to id or you can add extra route to your RouteConfig as following:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Activation",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{activationCode}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Authentication", action = "VerifyTheAccount" }
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

Note that the order of routes definition is very important.

Now when running the application you will get the following results:
[image: Debug result]

And inside the browser:
[image]

Comment: WOW...Thanks a million. You really saved my day. Hope to get to whatever nice wishes you have.

Comment: @ MahmoudHeretani Hi again. your solution worked correctly. But when I added another route like 
" routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Password",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{passwordResetCode}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Authentication", action = "ResetPassword" }
       );" The previous route doesn't work. I mean it again gets null value. Whenever I want to call its method I bring its route to the top of the other routes manually! And it gets work! You know I have to change each route's priority when I want to call its method. O.O Any Idea? Thanks In advance...

Comment: Wrong! Both routes are identical - the both accept between zero and 3 segments (the `Default` route will never be hit)

Comment: Please remove all routes and keep the default route, beside that change your all parameter names from passwordResetCode and activationCode to Id this should do the trick